# how to create a column from an existing one in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to add a column to a dataSet by compute it from an existing one :

```
val test=Seq("aaxxx","bbxxx","ccxxx").toDF
test.show : 
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|aaxxx|
|bbxxx|
|ccxxx|
+-----+
```

here is what I want :

```
+-----+----+
|value|val2|
+-----+----+
|aaxxx|aa  |
|bbxxx|bb  |
|ccxxx|cc  |
+-----+----+
```

for that I trried :

```
val column =test.select("value").as[String].map(e=>e.substring(0,2)).col("value")
test.withColumn("value2", column)
```

but I'm getting :

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) value#10 missing from value#1 in operator !Project [value#1, value#10 AS value2.#17]. Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: value. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;;
>   !Project [value#1, value#10 AS value2.#17]
>   +- LocalRelation [value#1]

can anyone see what is the issue with my code, or have a better way to get the needed result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the spark sql function substring to get the first two caracters like that:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.function.{substring, col}
val newDf = test.withColumn("val2", substring(col("value"), 0, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

> use withcolumn with substring

```
scala> val test=Seq("aaxxx","bbxxx","ccxxx").toDF

scala> test.show()
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|aaxxx|
|bbxxx|
|ccxxx|
+-----+

scala> test.withColumn("val2",substring(col("value"),1,2)).show
+-----+----+
|value|val2|
+-----+----+
|aaxxx|  aa|
|bbxxx|  bb|
|ccxxx|  cc|
+-----+----+
```

hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Here are three ways how to do it:

1) Using a function `substring`, which has to be imported

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{substring}

test.withColumn("value2", substring($"value", 0, 2))
```

2) Calling a method `substr` on column object

```
test.withColumn("value2", $"value".substr(0, 2))
```

3) Using a SQL expression:

```
test.selectExpr("value", "substring(value, 0, 2) AS value2")
```